# Existe diferença entre "ao encontro de" e "de encontro a"?

Tags: significado, expressões

Normalmente vejo essas expressões serem usadas para expressar concordância (ex.: "essa medida vai ao encontro de nossos objetivos"). As duas formas significam a mesma coisa? Qual o modo mais apropriado de usá-las?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não significam a mesma coisa; inclusive, [tem significados opostos](http://www.brasilescola.com/gramatica/ao-encontro-ou-encontro-a.htm).

*Ao encontro de* = *em direção a*, expressa concordância.

*De encontro a* = *em oposição a*, expressa discordância. (Usando o exemplo que você deu, *a medida vai de encontro aos nossos objetivos* = *A medida vai contra nossos objetivos*)

Answer (score 4):

As duas expressões não tem o mesmo significado.

**Ao encontro de**: tem significado de “estar de acordo com”, “em direção a”, “favorável a”, “para junto de”.

Por exemplo: 
Essa lei vem ao encontro dos interesses da população. (Essa lei vem a favor, em direção aos interesses da população)

Já a expressão **de encontro a** tem significado de “contra”, “em oposição a”, “para chocar-se com”.
Por exemplo:
O jovem dirigiu bêbado e foi de encontro à árvore. (O jovem dirigiu bêbado e chocou-se com a árvore).

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que quando "você vai AO ENCONTRO DE" refere-se a alguém.
Já quando diz "fui DE ENCONTRO A", pra mim parece que você bateu em algo/objeto, como um acidente.
Minhas sugestões de frases:

-"Estava de carro e fui ao encontro de João".
-"Estava de carro e fui de encontro ao poste".

ou ainda:

-"Saí de casa ao encontro escolar".
-"Caí da escada e fui de encontro ao chão"